# Magento 1.9 extend core class

Tags: php, magento, model, magento-1.9, extend

I would like to extend core product class and add some functionality.

I made file app\code\local\ast\Catalog\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
         <ast_Catalog>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </ast_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product>ast_Catalog_Model_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
   </global>
</config>
```

second file app\etc\modules\ast_Catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
        <ast_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </ast_Catalog>
     </modules>
</config>
```

and file Product.php in app\code\local\ast\Catalog\Model\

```
class ast_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product 
{

    public function makeBlue() 
    {
        echo 'makeBlue';
    }   

}
```

Now when I try to use my function makeBlue() in app\design\frontend\ast\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml file

```
<div class="product-shop">
 <?php 
               ....
               echo 'hello';
               echo $this->makeBlue(); 
               ....       
 ?>
```

I have got error below:

```
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View::makeBlue(Array
(
)
)

#0 I:\WWW\Sklep_www4\app\design\frontend\ast\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml(45): Varien_Object->__call('makeBlue', Array)
.......
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I extend class ast_Catalog_Model_Product not Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View. After change extend class to Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't respect the naming convention when creating your module. Module namespace and module name should start with an uppercase letter, try changing "ast" to "Ast" in xml, class names, and folder name